# find a record across multiple python pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say, I have three dataframes as follows, and I would like to find in which dataframes a particular record exists.

this is dataframe1 (df1)

```
index | name | acct_no | country
2 | alex | 112233 | USA
3 | rider | 223344 | Mexico
```

This is dataframe2 (df2)

```
index | name | acct_no | country
2 | alex | 112233 | USA
3 | keith | 993344 | Brazil
```

This is dataframe3 (df3)

```
index | name | acct_no | country
2 | alex | 112233 | USA
3 | hopper | 444444 | Canada
```

So, if I run the following code, I can find all the information about acct_no 112233 for a single dataframe.

```
p = df1.loc[df1['acct_no']=112233]
```

But, I would like to know which code will help me find out that acct_no 112233 exists in df1, df2, df3

Comment: What do you want to do with the output?

Comment: may be `df1.loc[~df1['acct_no']==112233].isin(array)]`  or `df1[[df1['acct_no']==112233].isin([0, 1, 2])`

Comment: you are right. i just to check if the records exist in all dataframes @Georgy.

Comment: Why not just create one big `DataFrame`? `df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'])`

Comment: I dont want to do anything with the output, just want to know if the record exists in any of the dataframes. @ALollz

Comment: Creating a big dataframe concatenating all dataframes may not help my solution because I would like to know in which separate dataframes a record exists. Appreciate your cooperation @ALollz

Comment: @ArifulHaque, I understand, but in my case above, you create a hierarchical index, with the keys referencing which dataframe. Then it's as simple as `np.unique(df[df.acct_no==112233].index.get_level_values(0))` to see which frames it exists in all at once. Though probably unnecessary if you never need to get the other information...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One wat to know if the element is in the column `'acct_no'` of the dataframe is:

```
>> (df1['acct_no']==112233).any()
True
```

You could check all at the same time by doing:

```
>> all([(df['acct_no']==112233).any() for df in [df1, df2, df3]])

True
```